# Linux running a command inline to CURL command

Tags: shell, curl, cron, freebsd

I'm trying to run the file `sh /usr/local/sbin/script.sh` and assigning the `stderr` as parameter to `$msg`.

```
curl -k -X POST https://192.168.0.25/sims/index.php -d "option=com_user&task=sendSMSalert&msg=$(/usr/local/sbin/script.sh 2>&1)"
```

The above script works fine on Ubuntu but when running the same script on freenas 11, I'm getting the error:

> Illegal variable name.

I then tried replacing `$(/usr/local/sbin/script.sh 2>&1)` with (/usr/local/sbin/script.sh), but instead of output of `/usr/local/sbin/script.sh` command, It's just assigning the string `"/usr/local/sbin"` to that parameter.
Please help me.

Comment: The first syntax is correct; it's not clear what's triggering the error. I suspect it's a problem in the script, rather than the `curl` command line where it is called.

Comment: It may be more efficient, though, to let `curl` read the output of the script rather than reading it into memory first: `/usr/local/sbin/script.sh 2>&1 | curl ... -d "...&msg=@-"`.